# Identify deleted pages in onenote

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

How to get the list of pages deleted using OneNote API (To synch the offline content)?

Assume we have 10000 pages in OneNote which is cached locally. When a page is deleted in OneNote how to identify the delete operation using API?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the API currently does not support retrieving deleted (recycle bin) content. If you believe this is a feature we should have, please create/upvote items in our uservoice site.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

If what you are interested in are changes in user's content (deletes, adds, edits) then webhooks is what you should use. You basically subscribe to user's changes and get notified on any changes. You could cache the list of pages and on every change, identify which pages were added/deleted/edited. Note: only applies to consumer notebooks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sync